# How to get the output of a php file into a variable using mPDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

I'm using mPDF library to provide pdf files.

Assume that I have a file named `facture.php` that contains :

- an image in the header
- a table in the body
- an image in the footer of the file

And another file named `convert_HTML2PDF.php` that will provide the pdf output of the first file.

I would like to get the output of the facture file that is interpreted into a variable and output it as a pdf file without visualising in the browser.

How can I do that and use the output inside the convert_HTML2PDF.php?

Comment: Why not include the functionality of `convert_HTML2PDF.php` in your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'F');
```

will send the output to a file on your server instead of a browser.

See:
http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=125
For more output variations.

Answer (score 10):

```
$pdf = $mpdf->Output('', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::STRING_RETURN)
```

will output the PDF into a string - no need to create temp file.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php)** to get html content of your facture.php :

```
$output = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/facture.php');
```

Comment: I used this function and it works, but now, the problem is that in the facture.php there is two images that have not been displayed ! When i access locally facture.php the images are displayed.